# $0\to \text{Hom}(P_0,G)\to \text{Hom}(P_1,G)\to \text{Hom}(P_2,G)\to\dots$ is an exact sequence.

Tags: homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, group-cohomology, projective-module

I am reading ''Algebraic number theory'' by Cassels and Fröhlich and in the chapter IV.4 it says the following:

If $\dots\to P_2\to P_1\to P_0\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ is a projective resolution and $G$ is an abelian group then the following sequence is almost exact (all homology grups are $0$ except for the first one): $$0\to \text{Hom}(P_0,G)\to \text{Hom}(P_1,G)\to \text{Hom}(P_2,G)\to\dots$$

The only reasoning for this that is written in the book is ''Because all the $P_i$ are free as abelian groups''.

I know that the $\text{Hom}(-,G)$ is a contravariant left exact functor and when $G$ is injective it is exact (not sure if this helps here) but I don't know much about how to approach this problem. I know I shoudn't post a question without any try, but here I am totally lost, so I will understand that you won't solve the question for me, but any small hint will be thanked.

Comment: You have it the other way around -- when $G$ is *injective* the functor $\operatorname{Hom}({-},G)$ is exact. When $G$ is projective the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(G,{-})$ is exact.

Comment: Which “Algebraic number theory”? Several books have this exact title… also, $\mathrm{Hom}(-,G)$ is exact when $G$ is *injective*, not projective.

Comment: @Mindlack sorry, I've edited the post, just a typo, thanks.

Comment: If you’re in the category of abelian groups: the idea is that any two projective resolutions are homotopic and thus the homology of the second sequence doesn’t depend on what $P_{\cdot}$ is. But $P_0=\mathbb{Z}$, $P_i=0$ for $i>0$ is such a projective resolution with the required vanishing in homology.

Comment: @Mindlack I don't think that is what the book want me to do, since this is just a part of the proof that the homology is unique, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long exact sequence
$$\dots \to A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}} A_n \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n-1} \to \dots$$
can be broken down as a bunch of short exact sequences
$$0 \to \ker f_n \to A_n \to \operatorname{img} f_n \to 0$$
which stitch together via the equalities $\ker f_n = \operatorname{img} f_{n+1}$.

When we apply $\operatorname{Hom}({-},B)$ to the above short exact sequence, we get the long exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{img} f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\ker f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\operatorname{img} f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(A_n, B) \to \dots$$
If each $A_n$ is projective (as in your post), this yields an exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{img} f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\ker f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\operatorname{img} f_n, B) \to 0$$

In your situation, each $A_n$ is actually a free abelian group, and every subgroup of a free abelian group is free, so also each $\operatorname{img} f_n \leq A_{n-1}$ is free abelian. Thus this collapses to
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{img} f_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_n, B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\ker f_n, B) \to 0$$

Again since $\operatorname{img} f_{n+1} = \ker f_n$, these stitch together to give a long exact sequence
$$\dots \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_{n-1},B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_n,B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_{n+1},B) \to \dots$$

To make this whole argument even simpler: in your situation, the short exact sequences $0 \to \ker f_n \to A_n \to \operatorname{img} f_n \to 0$ are all split, because all three objects are free.

Comment: Warning: I didn't realize when I wrote this answer that the resolution in question was one of $G$-modules. There are some small adjustments that need to be made, but also this question is a duplicate of another with an accepted answer, so I've voted to close.